# Gradle 4.8.1 - Could not determine java version from '9.0.1' error

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle

I have noticed this issue has been extensively asked and 'solved' for someone but I cannot get it to work on my machine.

I am using cordova to build an Android App - as soon as I run "cordova build android" I get this output:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1
studio

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Grande -v:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.8.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-06-21 07:53:06 UTC
Revision:     0abdea078047b12df42e7750ccba34d69b516a22

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          9.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 9.0.1+11)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Java -version:

```
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

In some of the post I have seen, they had a really old version of Gradle and mine is the latest.

Any straight forward fix for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug on Cordova not correctly detecting the java version as it expect it to be in the form of 1.x (i.e. 1.9) and not 9.

Anyway, java 9 is not supported, you have to downgrade the JDK to java 8 as it's required by Android.

Comment: Thanks - you are right, I needed to downgrade to Java 8. I now have a different problem :( but that's for another question.